# Sorting is not working with <ngx-datatable> if the column name having special and camel characters in it

Tags: angular, sorting, angular2-template, ngx-datatable

I am using **ngx-datatable**. Sorting is not working  if the column name having **special and camel** characters in it.

**For example :**

In table I am having the following columns needs to be sorted:

1. displayName
2. first_name

Please can anyone provide me the solution?

Thanks and Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

sorry I do not post a comment yet, I just relate my experience,  I have worked with this grid, this is awesome, but I migrate to primeNG is best solution and are more flexible to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let col of columns" name="{{col.name}}" prop="{{col.prop}}" class='{{col.prop}}' [sortable]="false" [cellClass]="getCellClass">
<ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                        <span class="datatable-header-cell draggable unselectable" (click)="onSort($event,col.prop, col.sortAscending = !col.sortAscending)" title="{{col.desc}}">
                            {{col.name}}
                        </span>                       
                    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>

public columns: Array<any> = [
        { name: 'Display Name', prop: 'displayName', sortAscending: false }, 
        { name: 'First Name', prop: 'first_name', sortAscending: false }, 
        ];

private onSort(event: any, column: string, sortingType: boolean) {
//here update the resilt rows as per assending or desc
}
```